# What is MYSQL's default behavior when retrieving and inserting datetime? Running into a interesting problem of timezone offsets

Tags: mysql, node.js, timezone, momentjs

We have a server on UTC timezone in our testing environment and noticed that the times were coming out incorrectly in PDT.

The solution we came up with was to convert everything to UTC time prior to storing it into the database and then using moment-timezone to convert it back to the correct locale timezone on retrieval.

I'm running into an interesting issue where the UTC timezone conversion is working correctly (e.g. if an event takes place at 8:00am PDT, it stores it as 15:00 UTC, correct difference of +7 hours). All of the conversions take place on the client side before it is passed to the server as a string until it is finally stored into the database. After running a query in the database, I see it as expected in the correct format of 15:00.

However, when I am retrieving the data, it is adding an additional 7 hours and returning 22:00. I've logged this out on all of the controller routes and confirmed that there are no other additional modifications happening to the date object anywhere on the server, so am I correct in assuming this is a default behavior with MYSQL that I need to be aware of?

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening?

Used moment-timezone to convert local client-side time to UTC and storing it as a string. Passing this to the controller to insert into the database.

Confirmed Database is storing the information correctly as expected.

Output is incorrect with 7+ hours added on.

```
// This is on the client side where it formats the date using moment to convert it to UTC from locale time
function convertTimeToUTCTimezone(date) {
  const timezone = "America/Vancouver"; // TODO make this more applicable across different time zones in the future

  const formatDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  const formatTimezoneDate = moment.tz(formatDate, 
  timezone).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  return formatTimezoneDate;
}
```

The date entered into a form is:
2019-06-14 8:00:00 (8am PDT, which is UTC - 7hours)

The date string passed from client to server is:
2019-06-14T15:00:00.000Z

The datetime I expect to see via MySQL query is: (correct)
2019-06-12 15:00:00

I expect the time retrieved from it to equal: (expected)
2019-06-14T15:00:00.000Z

But I am getting: (issue)
2019-06-14T22:00:00.000Z

**[UPDATE]**
mysql database, column defined as DATETIME

Insert example:

```
// Using objectionJS
static async function insertToTable(formData) {
  // formData is an object of key-value pairs, keys matching database column names
  return this.query().insert(formData);
}
```

Comment: Too many things are involved in the process. For the start: what is your system timezone, mysql timezone and column type? Have you logged your insert/update query that is putting the datetime into mysql? Do you do formatting with sql or in server side programming language (like creating object and using some function to format)?

Comment: @fifonik System timezone is "America/Vancouver - Pacific Daytime Timezone". I logged the object being inserted into the insert query and confirmed that it is still the same string value that was converted to UTC from the client side, which is as expected. There is formatting on the server side, but I've made sure that the date itself is not touched, only formatted on client side. Once it's in the server, it is a string value all the way until it enters the database insert query. 

I've checked and do not believe there is any formatting being done in mysql, unless it is defaulting something.

Comment: Please update your post with 1) an example "Insert", 2) what type you've defined the column (e.g. MySql "DATETIME")

Comment: @paulsm4 . Updated

Comment: If I understand correctly, the datetime is converted on client side to UTC, sent to server as string in UTC format and then inserted into MySQL "as is". Is that correct?

Comment: @fifonik Yes that is correct. I played around with modifying the date object in the server, but ran into issues with the server timezone affecting it so client-side passes it as string to prevent the server from making any adjustments to a date object.

Comment: When datetime is inserted into mysql it is assumed to be in system/mysql timezone, not in UTC. So the datetime that on client was 2019-06-14 8:00:00 PTD in fact in MySQL was added as 2019-06-14 15:00:00 PTD that is 2019-06-14 22:00:00 UTC. Sure, it is up to your code what to do with the date and you can do the double TZ shift when returning it. However, I'd recommend to avoid the double conversion. One way to do this - parse datetime from from client into local server datetime using nodejs.

Comment: @fifonik I see. I've accounted for this and have set the global time_zone and session time_zone to '+00:0'. In this scenario, if the server is on timezone '+0:00', shouldn't it resolve the issue? Will look into the parse datetime method

Comment: I do not think so. The change should only affect how TIMESTAMP stored internally.  MySQL is not converting datetimes automatically. When you  storing '2019-06-14 08:00:00' in DATETIME and then retrieving it (without formatting), you will get the same value. Later your code "printing" it into 8601 format. Here is when additional TZ shift applied as nodejs code expecting the datetime is in local timezone. I think you can only have 2 ways. Convert all datetimes into local timezone before storing or format some of them in different way after getting from DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what the value for the "Date/Time" column in your actual MySQL "INSERT" statement looks like.  I'm also curious what type you defined it to be in your MySql table.

In general, I would recommend:

- Defining date, time and datetime columns as type "DATETIME"
- If possible, set a default constraint and use "NOW()" for your INSERT.  This will use the server's date/time/timezone.

From this link:

> https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-time-zones-in-mysql
>
> A complete generic approach would be to have two DATETIME columns to
>   store the utc_datetime and the local_datetime, while a VARCHAR column
>   stores the IANA time_zone string (the longest one at the moment is
>   “America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia”, which has 32 characters).

Whatever you decide, I would consider doing most of the "work" on the MySql/server side, vs. in your Javascript client.

Comment: Model: 
  start: '2019-06-13 15:00:00',
  end: '2019-06-30 15:00:00',

Client-side: 
 Entered 8:00am in PDT, converted to UTC = '2019-06-xx 15:00:00'

Console.log(...) on server in GET request:
 Returns... start: 2019-06-13T22:00:00.000Z

Type for the date is set to DATETIME currently.

The work on the clientside for the local to UTC time conversion takes place since the server's timezone was causing issues with time retrieval, on the client side, but will try and find a way to do this on the server side if possible.